# Why missing key prop error is not reported any more in VS Code?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

`eslint-plugin-react` used to throw warning/errors **in VS Code** when `key` prop is missing when iterating a list in JSX, but it does not do the job anymore. (Error is thrown in the browser console.)

Code sample with missing `key` prop (forked from React beta docs)

```
import { people } from './data.js';
import { getImageUrl } from './utils.js';

export default function List() {
  const chemists = people.filter(person =>
    person.profession === 'chemist'
  );
  const listItems = chemists.map(person =>
    <li>
      <img
        src={getImageUrl(person)}
        alt={person.name}
      />
      <p>
        <b>{person.name}:</b>
        {' ' + person.profession + ' '}
        known for {person.accomplishment}
      </p>
    </li>
  );
  return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
}
```

.eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "rules":{
    "react/jsx-key": "error"
  }
}
```

AFAIK React by default use array index if no `key` value is passed, but lint rules are there for to help developers with the code in the editor/IDE.

Here is the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eslint-no-key-prop-warning-ny2e86?file=%2FApp.js%3A0-509)

**What I tried?**

- Configuring ESLint to throw error on missing `key` prop.
- Tried adding eslint dependencies to both `devDependencies`, `dependencies` blocks, hoping something wrong with Code Sandbox
- Tried similar setup in locally in VS Code.
- Also tried `eslint-config-react-app` which is mentioned [in new docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/editor-setup#linting) (even though it may be using same plugin under the hood)

ESlint versions:

```
"eslint": "8.25.0",
"eslint-config-react-app": "7.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "7.31.10"
```